# Why can I separate digits with an apostrophe in C++ but not C?

Tags: c++, c

I saw this vector declaration in a code sample

```
std::vector<double> v(10'000'007, 0.5);
```

which produces a vector of size 10000007, so it must be cast as a size_type. I can also assign it to a variable of type `size_t` which isn't surprising. This same declaration does not compile in C, however, I get an error

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
unsigned x = 10'000'007;
printf("x: %d\n", x);
}

warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar] unsigned x = 10'000'007;
error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before '\x303030'
```

This style makes it easier to read the declaration, but was there really a rule added to C++ to make this compile?

Comment: They are different languages with a different set of features. C++ allows this, C does not.

Comment: This is a feature added to C++14

Comment: "was there really a rule added to C++ to make this compile?" c++ is not just c with some rules added. If you see it like this, you wont have much fun with c++ (and I guess neither with c). They are different languages. C++ comes from C, but both lanuages have diverged since then

Comment: For C, `#define X(a,b,c) a ## b ## c`, then use `unsigned x = X(10,000,007);`  But just do this for fun, not for real code that you'd want anyone else to see.

Answer (score 7):

In C++14, integer literals were updated to allow an optional `'` separator.

Refer to [lex.icon]

> *decimal-literal*:
>        *nonzero-digit*
>        *decimal-literal `’`<sub>opt</sub> digit*

So the code snippet you've shown will not compile in any C++ standard below C++14, and the C language does not yet have this rule.

Comment: "Yet" sounds quite optimistic. Has there been any proposal to add this to C?

Comment: @Ruslan: Lol not that I'm aware of, but I'm not denying the possibility!

Comment: i am surprised you have answered this question. C & C++ are distinct languages with their own syntax and semantics. So I will extend this question: what about D, C#, ADA & Prolog?

Comment: @P__J__: That's an interesting criticism to levy, since C++ considers itself a superset of a subset of the C language, and it's oftentimes difficult for newcomers to the languages to distinguish the differences.

Comment: It is common misunderstanding - it is not superset or subset. There are completely different even if sometimes one may see some similarities.

Comment: @P__J__ one cannot point out often enough that c and c++ are two different languages, but once this misconception is out of the way there is no point in denying that they have some common history. Imho the question is perfeclty valid and deserves an answer

Comment: @P__J__: You cannot ignore the fact that the C++ standard explicitly points at the C standard in places to describe the behavior of some operations.

Comment: Even if they have some common points it does not change that they are different languages. C# is very similar as well.

Comment: @P__J__: It says it right there in the C++ standard: "C++ is a general purpose programming language based on the C programming language as described in
ISO/IEC 9899:2011 Programming languages — C (hereinafter referred to as the C standard). In addition to
the facilities provided by C, C++ provides additional data types, classes, templates, exceptions, namespaces,
operator overloading, function name overloading, references, free store management operators, and additional
library facilities." So yes, it is a superset of a specific version of C (although in practice this is not always true)

Comment: one could remove any reference to C from the question and from the answer it they still would be substantially the same... maybe this debate is rather pointless... ;)

Comment: *During the development of the .NET Framework, the class libraries were originally written using a managed code compiler system called Simple Managed C (SMC).[18][19] In January 1999, Anders Hejlsberg formed a team to build a new language at the time called Cool, which stood for "C-like Object Oriented Language"*  So using this logic C# i superset of C

Comment: And what aboud *D* which is "modified  C++"

Comment: @P__J__: This will be last comment on the matter, because I'm not sure if you're trolling or not. I do not agree that the quotes you have provided indicate that C# is intended to be a superset of C, rather that it was written using some variation of C.

Comment: @P__J__ • Neither C# nor D have a relationship to C++ or C, like C++ does to C.  C++/CLI has that kind of relationship to C++.  C++/CX has that kind of relationship to C++.  Most languages are only inspired or influenced by one or a few languages that came before them, rather than having their specification tethered to another language.